# Combine 2 excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in column C i have a text with "xxx has been deleted because... " or "xxx have been deleted because... " . I have 2 formulas:

```
=IF(C3<>"",IF(FIND("has been deleted",C3),LEFT(C3,FIND("has been deleted",C3)-1),"DDDD"),"AAAAAAA")
```

and

```
=IF(C5<>"",IF(FIND("have been deleted",C5),LEFT(C5,FIND("have been deleted",C5)-1),"DDDD"),"AAAAAAA")
```

I want to combine the two but it doesn't work. Here is what i have tried :

```
=IF(C4<>"",IF(FIND("have been deleted",C4),LEFT(C4,FIND("have been deleted",C4)-1),IF(FIND("has been deleted",C3),LEFT(C3,FIND("has been deleted",C3)-1),"DDDD")),"AAAAAAA")

=IF(C4<>"",IF(FIND("have been deleted",C4),LEFT(C4,FIND("have been deleted",C4)-1),LEFT(C3,FIND("has been deleted",C3)-1)),"AAAAAAA")
```

Comment: are you basically trying to check for "has" and "have" variations in the same formula?

Comment: hey @wittman,  i've suggested a formula for you. if this solves your problem, pls don't forget to mark my asnwer as "Answer". Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

formula:

```
=IF(C1="",  "AAAAAAA",
    IF(  AND( ISERROR( FIND("has been deleted",C1)), 
              ISERROR( FIND("have been deleted",C1))),
        "DDDD",
        LEFT(C1,  IFERROR( FIND("has been deleted",C1), 
                           FIND("have been deleted",C1)) -1))
 )
```

and here is my test based on the sample you described:

[image: TEST]

please note formula needs pasting into D1 and dragged down. as in picture

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time.

Answer (score 2):

=IF(C1="","AAAAAA",IF(OR(ISERROR(FIND("have been deleted",C1)),ISERROR(FIND("have been deleted",C1))),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("has been deleted",C1)),LEFT(C1,FIND("has been deleted",C1)-1),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("have been deleted",C1)),LEFT(C1,FIND("have been deleted",C1)-1),"DDDDD"))))

Please enter this formula into D1 and it will show result based on value C1.
I hope we understood your question properly.

Comment: Hi, it gives false for have been deleted but thank you for your answer and time.

Comment: =IF(C1="","AAAAAA",IF(OR(ISERROR(FIND("have been deleted",C1)),ISERROR(FIND("has been deleted",C1))),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("has been deleted",C1)),LEFT(C1,FIND("has been deleted",C1)-1),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("have been deleted",C1)),LEFT(C1,FIND("have been deleted",C1)-1),"DDDDD"))))

Comment: Yes, you are right. I copied the wrong formula. Try this one.